# how this useTransition hook works in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just playing around with the reactjs `useTransition` hook and trying to understand how to use it. I've gone through almost everything on the [doc](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useTransition). The example given there is working as expected.

I'm trying to use this hook in a different context, but this time it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code below:

```js
import { useState, useTransition } from "react";

function Component() {
  const [slow, setSlow] = useState(0);
  const [fast, setFast] = useState(0);

  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  const handleSlowClick = () => {
    startTransition(() => {
      let starting = performance.now();
      while (performance.now() - starting < 5000) {
        // do nothing for 5sec
      }
      setSlow((prev) => prev + 1);
    });
  };

  const handleFastClick = () => {
    setFast((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleSlowClick}>slow - {slow}</button>
      <button onClick={handleFastClick}>fast - {fast}</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Component;
```

react is supposed to give everything inside the `startTransition` function less priority when updating states. But this isn't the case in the browser. When I click the `slow` button, it makes the whole web page unresponsive for 5 sec

I wonder what's happening under the hood?

[NOTE: I'm trying it inside my current NextJS project, in case it matters]

Comment: In the docs it waits 1 milliseconds not 5 seconds or I'm looking on a wrong example

Comment: In the docs, it waits for 1ms per <SlowPost />. and the Post button is rendering 500 <SlowPost />. So in total it's waiting for 1*500 = 500ms. But end of the conversation, i really don't think this timer matters in this issue. I'm trying to use the `useTransition` on a different context than the doc, that's why i decided to change the timer as well

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I was super confused too. The `useTransition` [docs page](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition) isn't really clear yet. So I toyed a bit with the little `Posts (slow)` example on the page to see how it worked, and noted a couple fundamental things:

- I found that, if you increase the while-loop delay from 1ms to 1000ms (1 second), it won't let you switch between tabs until the latest `SlowPost` component finishes rendering.
- I also added a `console.log` in the for-loop that iteratively generates the slow posts, as well as a `console.log` in the `SlowPost` component renderer and noticed that the for-loop runs through all of them very quickly, and only *afterward* does each `SlowPost` render (one at a time, slowly). What I later came to realize is that this render order is standard for React. The render functions are always called from the outside inward, and the components are only composed together afterward.

With these two points in mind, I think I understand 'concurrency' mode correctly then:

*Clarification:* It's not using an actual separate thread (e.g., No web workers here. Otherwise you can't get real DOM access, DOM refs would become impossible, etc.)

Instead, since components render calls are made separately (i.e., not recursively), in concurrency mode, React simply separates the calls *asynchronously* (again, not on a different thread). That is, it uses a short `setTimeout` between each component render, allowing it to pick up on other user interactions like clicks, touches, etc. and cancel the long rendering process if an interaction eliminates the need for it.

So, basically, when a re-render is somehow triggered from inside a `startTransition` callback, React hops into 'concurrency' mode for the component, so that, when rendering a component like,

```
<Parent>
    <Child1 />
    <Child2 />
    <Child3 />
</Parent>
```

the rendering process simply *waits* between component renders:

```
// Pseudocode:

<Parent>
    <*placeholder1 [Child1]*>
    <*placeholder2 [Child2]*>
    <*placeholder3 [Child3]*>
</Parent>

listenForEvents();

placeholder1 = <Child1 />

listenForEvents();

placeholder2 = <Child2 />

listenForEvents();

placeholder3 = <Child3 />
```